# Disabling buttons when all correct answers have been selected

Tags: java, android

I have figured out how to select all possible correct answers in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48721615/selecting-multiple-correct-answers-from-buttons), the problem is the question would only move on to the next round by selecting the wrong answer, which then the next button would appear.

All correct answers have been selected.

[image: All correct answers have been selected.]

Next button would only appear when a wrong answer is selected.

[image: Next button would only appear when a wrong answer is selected.]

I modified my code from the previous question I posted to this:

```
public void answerButtonClickHandler(View v)
{
    Answer answer = answers.get(v.getId());
    if (answer != null) {
        questionAnswered++;
        if (answer.isCorrect()) {
            correctlyAnswered++;
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.answer_button_correct);
        } else{
            disableAnswerButtons();
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.answer_button_wrong);
            questionDescriptionText.setText(question.getDescription());
            questionDescriptionText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            nextBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }



        if (nextQuestionIndex >= questionsIndexList.size()) {

        //} else{
            completeBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If there is a previous post that contains context for your question, you should include that information here as if a stand-alone question. Your question seems to lack information necessary to answer which I assume is in that previous post.

Comment: Oops, sorry. My previous question can be viewed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48721615/selecting-multiple-correct-answers-from-buttons).